# MYSQL Query Tuning for updating data of one table by data of next table

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, sql-update, database-tuning

I do have two tables:

```
1. PersonAddressList [About 5,000 records]
   Columns:
   ID int
   TITLE varchar
   CITY varchar

2. CityList [About 5,000 recods]
   Columns:
   ID int
   City_Name varchar
   City_State int //[RK to State]
```

Previous designer had added city names directly in table 1 [personaddresslist]. Now I am normalising it and replacing the city name in table 1 with city id in table 2

Query I have used:

> Update personaddresslist, CityList set CITY = cityList.ID where CITY =
>   City_name

The above query runs good if the tables have less data, but keeps on rolling n rolling in case of both tables has large no of data. In my real scenario I do medium set of data about 5000 records in each table.

So how do can we tune it fine.

Regards,
Kabindra

Edit 1:
Regarding the result from above query, it took me nearly 40 mins to complete the running of script, Since I need to run the similar script on other more tables, I would like to fine tune and make it faster.

Comment: Can you share result of explain?

Answer (score 0):

Your table needs some modification and indexes to make it faster.

- First thing you are storing the `city` in `PersonAddressList`  table and the data type is `varchar` so even if its indexed it will never use it since they are of different data type in both tables.
- Then use of proper index.

I will start with

```
alter table PersonAddressList add index city_idx(CITY);
alter table CityList add index City_Name_idx(City_Name);
```

Then will use the following update command

```
update PersonAddressList p 
join CityList c on c.City_Name = p.CITY
set p.CITY = c.ID
```

The above query will be faster, just make sure that both `CITY` and `City_Name` are of same data type with the same size before applying the indexes.

Once the data is updated then you need to fix the structure

```
drop index city_idx from PersonAddressList ;

alter table PersonAddressList change CITY CITY int ;

alter table PersonAddressList add index city_idx(CITY);
```

and finally make sure that the `CityList` `ID` is indexed and if its primary key which is most likely it will be indexed by default.

Comment: Offtopic: question, why do you use ALTER TABLE when you need CREATE INDEX? It does the same (in MySQL), but it makes more sense to me. Just a habit or is it that I'm missing something?

Comment: @FrankHeikens you spotted right just a habit. May be its a bad one and if yes I will need to change it soon.